# Can't connect to spark-master in pyspark app using Docker:

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have used the next docker-compose to build the containers:

```
version: '3'
services:
  spark-master:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./conf/log4j.properties
        target: /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/log4j.properties
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
    networks:
      - spark
  spark-worker-1:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./conf/log4j.properties
        target: /opt/bitnami/spark/conf/log4j.properties
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    networks:
      - spark
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
networks:
  spark:
    driver: bridge
```

And the inspection of the network:

[image]

Finally, I use the next configuration in the Spark Session object:

```py
def get_spark_context(app_name: str) -> SparkSession:

    conf = SparkConf()

    conf.setAll(
        [
            (
                "spark.master",
                os.environ.get("SPARK_MASTER_URL", "spark://spark-master:7077"),
            ),
            ("spark.driver.host", os.environ.get("SPARK_DRIVER_HOST", "local[*]")),
            ("spark.submit.deployMode", "client"),
            ('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
            ("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0"),
            ("spark.app.name", app_name)
        ]
    )

    return SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

I'm using Spark Structured streaming, when I try to create the SparkSession object I get the next error:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties Setting default log level to "WARN". To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel). 21/09/09 15:58:04 WARN SparkContext: Please ensure that the number of slots available on your executors is limited by the number of cores to task cpus and not another custom resource. If cores is not the limiting resource then dynamic allocation will not work properly! 21/09/09 15:58:07 WARN TransportClientFactory: DNS resolution failed for spark-master:7077 took 2266 ms 21/09/09 15:58:07 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master spark-master:7077 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:302)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.client.StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint$$anon$1.run(StandaloneAppClient.scala:106)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-master:7077
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:253)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:195)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
        ... 4 more Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:156)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:153)
        at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:41)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:61)
        at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:53)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:55)
        at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:31)
        at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:106)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:200)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:46)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:180)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:166)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:577)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:551)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:490)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:615)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:604)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:984)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:504)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:417)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:474)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        ... 1 more INFO:py4j.java_gateway:Error while receiving.
```

The docker ps command returns the next result:
[image]

I don't exactly know where the problem is, all I want is running a python app using pyspark in a Docker container.

Comment: is the connection issue from `spark-worker-1`? also, add any configuration as code formatted text instead of images please

Comment: I don't exactly know where the issue come from. I already edited it...

Comment: What did you run before getting this error?

Comment: I run a python script:

python script.py

Comment: I meant regarding the docker issue - what commands did you run before the issue came to light?

Comment: I run docker-compose ( the file I shared), then I run the script which calls SparkSession as I also shared and finally, the error appears. I didn't run any command before that.

Comment: meaning the script you shared is not dockerized? i.e. it is not in a docker container in the compose file?

Comment: No it isn't, I'm developing an app in PyCharm and I wanted to test the script

Comment: ok, that might be easy to fix, just to make sure can you send the command output from `docker ps` and try and replace in the PyCharm script from `spark://spark-master:7077` to `spark://localhost:7077`?

Comment: I edited the post so you can see docker ps output. I tried replacing spark-master by localhost and appeared a different error:

ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Can only call getServletHandlers on a running MetricsSystem

Comment: Can you send the whole connection string?

Comment: Do you mean the output when I execute the SparkSession.builder.config(......?
https://i.imgur.com/StMsR5f.png

Comment: no no, the connection string with the `localhost:7077` but with protocol and everything

Comment: How can I check the connection string? Sorry for asking this kind of questions, this technology is totally new for me

Comment: The connection is the part where you define how to connect to the backend service serving the application, in your case it would start with the protocol `spark://` then host, port and path. I know you've sent previous versions of it but I want to make sure it's as it should be

Comment: I know, I mean how can I check it

Comment: It's this part os.environ.get("SPARK_MASTER_URL", "spark://spark-master:7077")

Comment: I supose it's: `spark://spark-master:7077/`

Comment: Ok then change it both in the script and the environment variables to `spark://localhost:7077` and that's for the script that runs directly on the host, the same host that runs the containers

Comment: The environment variable in the IDE, in the OS or in the docker-compose?

Comment: The one you're running it from, or all of them to be in the sure side